# Hierarchical JPEG Encoder/Decoder

Tags: compression, jpeg, encoder, decoder

Does anyone knows of any implementation of the hierarchical JPEG mode (ITU T.81) ? I am not talking about progressive mode (or sequential), I really mean the hierarchical mode.

Comment: There's no code, but http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~ryerraballi/MSB/pdfs/M4L1_HJPEG.pdf looks like a pretty good reference. As long as you have a normal JPEG compressor, it doesn't seem too complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some googling, I finally found out:

- https://github.com/thorfdbg/libjpeg

Which was referenced from:

- http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/progressive-jpegs-a-new-best-practice/

This seems by far the more advanced option. Some other results showed:

- http://flying_oe.tripod.com/academic/SoC/cs3242/index.html

And some explanations from:

- http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~ryerraballi/MSB/Contents.html