# JPEG Lossless in DICOM

Tags: jpeg, dicom, python-imaging-library

In the [DICOM spec](http://www.dicomlibrary.com/dicom/transfer-syntax/) one of the Transfer Syntaxes is `1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70` defined as `JPEG Lossless, Nonhierarchical, First- Order Prediction (Processes 14 [Selection Value 1])`.

What does "JPEG Lossless, Nonhierarchical, First- Order Prediction (Processes 14 [Selection Value 1])" mean? Is this format the same as JPEG-LS? [This page](http://mudicom.dcmdb.org/transfer_syntax.html) seems to indicate that there is some difference (JPEG-LS is listed in the bottom section).

Is is possible to read or write this format in Python? Looking over the docs for [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html) is no clear to me that the format is supported.

[This post is somewhat relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170199/how-to-decode-manually-jpeg-lossless-non-hierarchical-first-order-prediction).

Answer (score 6):

**JPEG Lossless First Order**

```
Identical to the main JPEG lossless, but with a constrained value for the
predictor, giving a slightly simplified algorithm, with slightly greater
speed, but slightly less compression on most images (2-5% typically)
(from medicalconnections wiki)
```

You may have a look at GDCM for encoding jpeg compressed dicom images.
[GDCM Wiki Link](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Answer (score 6):

JPEG Lossless and JPEG-LS are very  different implementation for image compression. JPEG lossless is defined in standard document: ITU-T T.81, ISO/IEC IS 10918-1, while JPEG-LS is defined in ITU-T T.87, ISO/IEC IS 14495-1.

JPEG-LS is a very different approach from all other JPEG-* compression family, since in its lossy form it is setup with a maximum bias from the original pixel. So you can generate a lossy JPEG-LS from an input file, where at maximum the difference in between the generated pixel and the original one, the difference is -say- 2.

Most toolkit on UNIX wont support JPEG Lossless originally because of some patent issue with the arithmetic codec:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding#US_patents

Therefore IJG (aka libjpeg) is a very limited implementation of ITU T.81 and only provides by default on UNIX distribution the lossy 8bits compression form of the standard (sequential & progressive but [not hierarchical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747709/hierarchical-jpeg-encoder-decoder)). Neither the lossy 12bits, nor the lossless 16bits is available. Technically the 12bits lossy should be possible, but since it requires a recompilation most (all?) distributions do not ship this "dual" library.

All of the above is also correct when using the new [libjpeg-turbo](http://libjpeg-turbo.virtualgl.org/) implementation, since libjpeg-turbo is only an optimized (binary compatible) version of the original libjpeg (version 6b to be precise).

Comment: Are there any libraries that handle decoding ITU-T T.81, ISO/IEC IS 10918-1 lossless? I know GDCM does but it expects an entire DICOM file rather than just image data.

Comment: @AlexRothberg GDCM is somewhat modular, so you can perfectly re-use the JPEG libraries used in GDCM for your own project (it's all good BSD style license)

Answer (score 3):

DICOM provides mechanism for supporting JPEG-LS Image Compression and DICOM standard PS 3.5 Annex A defines two different Transfer Syntaxes that reference the JPEG-LS Standard (ISO/IS-14495-1 (JPEG-LS Part 1). The Transfer Syntax with a UID of "1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.80" is lossless (bit preserving) and Transfer Syntax with a UID of "1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.81" is lossy (near-lossless) compression schemes.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I solved using @JohnnyQ hints in this way:

```
conda install -n myenv -c clinicalgraphics gdcm
conda install -n myenv -c anaconda pillow
```

Also you can use `pip install ...` to install **gdcm** and **pillow**.
Take a look at https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/image_data_handlers.html